# How do I dump a variable in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I am currently attempting to modify some open source software in JSP and am unaware of the syntax.

How does one dump a complex variable to the browser using JSP?

Comment: Perhaps you can use a debugger instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any variable and standard output, the variable class must implement the *.toString()* method. Then, you can send it to the renderized web page through the *[OutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)* in the *[HttpServletResponse](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)* object by using the <%= variable %>. For the *java.lang* classes it should be immediate.

For more complex classes, you need to implement the *.toString()* method:

```
class A {
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int z;

   public A(int x, int y, int z) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.z = z;
   }

   // XXX: this method...
   public String toString() {
       return "x = " + x + "; y = " + y + "; z = " + z;
   }
}
```

You must know that in JSP is no function/method such as *var_dump()* in PHP or *Data::Dumper* in Perl. In other case, you can send the output to the server *stdout* stream, by using *[System.out.println()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)*, but isn't a recommendable way...

Another option is to implement a static method that outputs all members on a well formatted string by using *[Java Introspection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html)*, but is a known issue that is not recommendable to use *Java Introspection* in production environments.

Comment: That pretty much covers all the bases, I think.  Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
<% out.println(variable); %>
```

Comment: This relies on `VariableClass` having a `toString()` method that renders its state properly; otherwise you'll be getting back something like `com.mypackage.VariableObject@35F0E3`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's anything you can do aside from manually run through the variable's properties.

```
<p>Prop1: <%= var1.prop1 %></p>
<p>Prop2: <%= var1.prop2 %></p>
```